# SharePoint team discussion list question

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my "Team discussion" list we ask user to select "Departments" from the drop down. Now, I'm creating view for each department so that they can only see their own discussions. But, When I add "Team discussion" list in a web part, I don't get my custom views in "Select View" drop down list. I'm getting only "Subject" view ,

[image]

I can do same for "Announcements" list but not for "Discussion" .

**Solution ::**  View must be created from "Subject" type and it works.. Don't find such restrictions anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the view you created was a "Private" view instead of a "Public" view.  Try creating the view from the discussion list's "Settings" page and then add it to a page.

Comment: Thanks.. It's a public view and created the same way as you suggested.